# Flutter Background Service how to judge apps goes back from background to foreground?

Tags: flutter, background-service

what I want achieve:

- judge app is in background or foreground inside a Background service;

what I have tried:

- I found is not possible to change background service while using WidgetBindingObserver to detect app's cycle;

this is my currently to detect apps cycle:

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    debugPrint('App State = $state');
    DbUserUranus? user = AppData.instance()!.user;
    if (user != null) {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
          state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        ChatApp.instance()!
            .eventsSender
            .sendPresence(PresenceType.Away, user.user_addr);
        GlobalSettings.isAppInBackground = true;
        debugPrint("----------------- ^^^^^^^^^^ App in background!!");


      } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        // MQTTClientWrapper.instance().connect();

        ChatApp.instance()!
            .eventsSender
            .sendPresence(PresenceType.Available, user.user_addr);
        GlobalSettings.isAppInBackground = false;
        debugPrint("---------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^ App comes back!");
      }
    }
  }
```

the questions is , the value I changed from main thread, doesn not takes effect in background service thread.

This is How can start a background service:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    debugPrint("now... to the background service!!!");
    var channel = const MethodChannel('com.example/background_service');
    // var serviceInst = MQTTService.instance();
    // var backgroundMain = serviceInst.startListen();
    var callbackHandle =
    PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(backgroundMain);
    channel.invokeMethod('startService', callbackHandle?.toRawHandle());
  }
```

any suggestions would be many thanks to!

Answer (score 1):

I used a Isolate and the flutter_background_service plugin.

You can achieve this with the following:

1. Setup a receiver with a ValueNotifier in your background service, this will receive the events from the UI
2. Setup a bool with a ValueNotifier in your background service this will be used to keep track of the state of the application.
3. In your UI, extends your widget with the WidgetsBindingObserver class, this will be used to catch application lifecycle events(resume, pause, inactive, etc)
4. Register your observer in the initState method.
5. override the didChangeAppLifecycleState event, this will be triggered once the lifecycle state of the application has been changed, this has a state parameter that you can use to get the current state of the app.

The UI Class:

class _ExampleState extends State with WidgetsBindingObserver{

SendPort? _sendPort;

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  ...
}

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  _sendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('appState');
  switch(state){
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      _sendPort?.send(false);
      break;
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      _sendPort?.send(true);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

The Service:

```
class RideBackgroundService {
  static final ValueNotifier<bool> _appPausedState = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  static final ValueNotifier<ReceivePort?> _stateNotifier = ValueNotifier<ReceivePort?>(null);

  ...

  static void onStart(ServiceInstance service) {
    if(_stateNotifier.value == null){
      _stateNotifier.value = ReceivePort('appState');
      IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(_stateNotifier.value!.sendPort, 'appState');
      _stateNotifier.value?.listen((dynamic value) {
        _appPausedState.value = serviceInfo.value as bool;
      });
    }
    ...
  }
```

Then you can use the _appPauseState.value to see the state of the application. Please keep in mind, its not possible to send instances, you should rather use basic data types like a int, or you could convert the object to a map and send that.

You can also do this via a stateless widget, i dont think it has to be a statefull widget, I just used a statefull widget in my project.

You can maybe also modify this code to send an int instead of a bool to get all of the states.